# Access denied - Laravel/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When i try to go on my app, i have this message :

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

But when i make `php artisan migrate`, that work and tables are create on my local database ...

When i open **mysql**, i have :

```
Service : Mysql@localhost:3306
User : root
Password : ****
```

and my **.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=development
APP_KEY=**********************************
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=localhost
TELESCOPE_ENABLED=true

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydatabase
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: My guess: Your CLI environment uses different DB credentials as your web environment

Comment: Check the password for the root account using PHPMyAdmin or something similair.

Comment: It's fix, i forgot to said, i use Homestead, and we have to use the Homestead database, not local.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a permission:-

**try:**  `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'your_user'@'localhost';`

The error on your site now is the permission denied.

Comment: not working, i tried `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';` but i have the same problem. Same with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`

Comment: @YannChapuis Can you please try with this ```php artisan config:clear``` and then open mysql